# Need a link or button click to trigger a php function on my Codeigniter site

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to know how I should be doing this. I feel like I'm missing something.

I have links and buttons on my main page that i want to trigger my PHP code. My PHP code varies.

I have one that uploads two xml files and loads them into my mysql table
one runs a large update query
one creates xml's from my sql table

I have them all working now. Thats not the problem. The problem is I hate how I am having to load another PHP page with just code then redirect back to the page i started on.

What i want is to be able to click the button or link and run the code then display on the page or bootstrap modal that its been done.

I was trying to have a bootstrap modal with progress bar pop up while running these functions then when done user clicks okay to close modal popup.

What is the best practice here? is this not conventional?

I have a CodeIgniter site setup with Ajax, Jquery and Bootstrap.

One other thing i looked at trying to do what using a controller or helper to do the work but i just can seem to understand the best practice.

Comment: Links in CodeIgniter always invoke a method of a controller. See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a controller specific for ajax operation and put all function in to that controller.

e.g.

```
class myajax extends CI_controller
{
   ... ... ....

 function create_xml()
{

}
```

}

and use site_url('myajax/create_xml') as location in ajax call.